# How to build only .app using electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am trying to fix a tricky production issue in electron app.

And electron-builder takes around 5-6 minutes to build

- project.app
- project.dmg
- project.mac.zip and so on.

Is there I can only build project.app and save time by not building .dmg file etc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add **dir** as target in your package.json

```
"build": {
    "appId": "app.id",
    "mac": {
        "category": "your.app.category.type",
        "target": "dir"
           }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can avoid dmg and mac and only serve `.app` files but you can avoid generating both dmg and zip file by specifying the target option in mac build config

```
"mac": {
  "target": [
    "dmg"
  ],

},
```

Comment: Tried the above, however it is building dmg and zip both again.

Answer (score 0):

If none of this work, you can always use a script to clean the .app file, run electron-builder as background process, then check until the .app file is built, kill the electron-builder process.